# How to retain elements from pandas dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have he below code like this which splits the address column and pops if length of add dict equal to 4 or 5(see code).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA",
                    "215 S 11th ST"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

for row in df_dict:
    add = row["address"]
    print(add.split("\\n"), len(add.split("\\n")))
    if len(add.split("\\n"))==4:
       target = add.split("\\n")
       target.pop(0)
       target = '\\n'.join(target)
    if len(add.split("\\n"))==5:
       target = add.split("\\n")
       target.pop(0)
       target.pop(1)
       target = '\\n'.join(target)
    print(target)
```

However, instead of giving condition to pop, I would like to retain last three elements of the dict with if `len(add.split("\\n") > 3` I need a command which retains only last three elements instead of popping the elements.

like this:

```
address
290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA
1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA
145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA
215 S 11th ST
``

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using pop(), it might work to use [slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/), like `target = target[-3:]`. This tells it to take only the last three items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use slicing in a `if-else` condition

**CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA",
                    "215 S 11th ST"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

for row in df_dict:
    add = row["address"]
    #print("original data",add.split("\\n"), len(add.split("\\n")))
    if len(add.split("\\n"))==4:
        target = add.split("\\n")[1:]
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    elif len(add.split("\\n"))==5:
        target = add.split("\\n")[2:]
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    elif len(add.split("\\n"))<=3:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    print(target)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
290 Valley Dr.\nCasper, WY 82604\nUSA
1180 Shelard Tower\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\nUSA
145 S. Durbin\nCasper, WY 82601\nUSA
215 S 11th ST
```

more optimize code it can work for `>3` even if it is `4` or a '100`.

```
for row in df_dict:
    add = row["address"]
    #print("original data",add.split("\\n"), len(add.split("\\n")))
    length=len(add.split("\\n"))
    print(length)
    if len(add.split("\\n"))<=3:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    if len(add.split("\\n"))>3:
        lengths=length-3
        target = add.split("\\n")[lengths:]
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    print(target)
```